# InertiaJS with Laravel & Vue2: Cannot redefine property: $inertia

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, inertiajs

I'm not sure why I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $inertia
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Object.install (app.js:108)
    at Function.Vue.use (app.js:233295)
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:246829)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.0 (app.js:253385)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:84
    at app.js:87
```

and this warning:

```
Registering the Inertia Vue plugin via the "app" component has been deprecated. Use the new "plugin" named export instead.

import { plugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'

Vue.use(plugin)
```

I followed the docs as closely as I could. I'm using Vue2 and Laravel 8. I can't find anyone with the same issues anywhere. The error claims that 'App' is no longer used, but the docs for Vue2 use it in their example. I'm confused, what am I missing?

Here is my code:

`resources/js/app.js`:

```
import { App, plugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(App)
Vue.use(plugin)

InertiaProgress.init()

Vue.component('drafts', require('./pages/Drafts').default)

const el = document.getElementById('app')

new Vue({
  render: (h) =>
    h(App, {
      props: {
        initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
        resolveComponent: (name) =>
          import(`./pages/${name}`).then((module) => module.default),
      },
    }),
}).$mount(el)
```

`resources/views/app.blade.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'AppealMaker') }}</title>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</head>

<body>
    @inertia
</body>

</html>
```

`web.php`:

```
Route::inertia('/drafts', 'drafts');
```

Comment: delete `Vue.use(App)` from app.js

Comment: That gives me this Vue error: `[Vue warn]: Do not mount Vue to <html> or <body> - mount to normal elements instead.`

Comment: what is content of `@inertia` template?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The page being loaded is the drafts page, it is a normal Vue file.

Comment: in `app.blade.php` wrap the directive `@inertia` in a div

Comment: That doesn't change the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228918/discussion-between-courtney-erickson-and-igor-moraru).

Comment: What version of ```inertia-vue``` are you using? I had a similar problem happen when running ```npm audit fix``` and a few of my dependencies were updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Here is how your app.js file must look like:

https://inertiajs.com/client-side-setup

summarizing:

- Remove:  Vue.use(App)
- Change:  import(`./pages/${name}`).then((module) => module.default),
  by   require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,